# Can I find out if a first time user of an app was referred to by a friend?

Tags: facebook, api

I am new to Facebook API. So, please pardon my ignorance.  I have looked around for an answer to my question, but did not find a solution.  We are developing an app, which will give a user an option to share with their friends.  I want to find out when if a user who comes to the app for the first time, was referred to by a user of the app, or by a link via a marketing campaign or came to know about the app because he/she is a fan of the page.  Is that possible?  I am more interested in knowing if that user was referred to by a user of the app.

Thanks

Sharma

Answer (score 1):

Add a ?referrer=x tag to your share links where x is the UID of the person sharing the link and use that to determine where the originating traffic is coming.  If this is for a tab app you'll need to use app_data to pass the info back to your app and then extract it from the signed request.  (more info: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/)

Comment: Out of curiosity, does this get around the issue where should the referred user need to authorize the app for the first time you lose all of the session information as Facebook takes over?

That was an issue I ran into when making a Facebook app that also wanted to track things.

Comment: Unfortunately to get the info for the incoming user you would still need to authorize them.  This will only get you the referrer and you'd have to tie the two together after authorizing the new user in the app.

Comment: One way you could actually track the originating share back to a user would be to use a friend selector and keep track of which friend the share had been sent to.  This would require some more upfront logic to keep track of where the share was being posted but could at least tell you which share was followed back. so referrer=posterUID&friend=targetUID at the end of the share link would add a layer of tracking info.